# Airflow cannot find local file

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

When using the FileToGoogleCloudStorageOperator from Airflow I keep getting this error when running my dag:

`"FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/ramonsotogarcia/Desktop/Data/pokemon.csv"`

I do not understand why Airflow is not finding my local file. This is my dag:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from airflow.contrib.operators.file_to_gcs import FileToGoogleCloudStorageOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_to_bq import GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago


#define variables

file = "pokemon.csv"
bucket = "modulo_spark_bucket"

destination_path = f"gs://{bucket}/data/{file}"
bucket = f"gs://{bucket}"
local_file = f"/Users/ramonsotogarcia/Desktop/Data/{file}"

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': days_ago(2),
    'email': ['sotogarcia.r@icloud.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 3,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}


my_dag = DAG(
    'fileSystem_toGCS_toBQ',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Loads data from local file into GCS and then transfer to BQ',
    schedule_interval=None,
)


t1 = FileToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(task_id = "local_to_gcs",
                                      src = local_file, 
                                      dst = destination_path, 
                                      bucket = bucket,
                                     dag = my_dag)

t2 = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(task_id = "GCS_to_BQ",
        bucket = bucket, 
        source_objects = [destination_path], 
        autodetect = True,
        skip_leading_rows = 1,
        create_disposition = "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
        destination_project_dataset_table = "neural-theory-277009.pokemon_data.pokemons",
        dag = my_dag)


#dependencies
t1 >> t2
```

Any ideas? I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but have you tried specifying the drive in the filepath, i.e.

```
f"C:/Users/ramonsotogarcia/Desktop/Data/{file}"
```

In case your airflow and the csv are on different disks.

Comment: Nothing... Tried changing it as you indicated, but still showing the same error. As per the documentation a relative path is accepted, so I don't understand why it is failing. I am running Airflow on GCP's cloud composer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still finding out the answer ?
You can try to put your csv into Dags folder. Then, open the Docker-compose.yaml file and find out the volumns keyword, you will see something like this: ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags. Now, local_file = "/opt/airflow/dags/file". Hope this will help you.